# Javascript: Code doesn't get executed when put into function

Tags: javascript

I have this working Javascript code which does some resizing on `init` and `resize`:

```
(function (w) {

  w.init = function () {

    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight; 

    //resize_font;
    var fs = parseInt(w / 26);   
    document.body.style.fontSize = fs + "px";

    //resize_cover;
    var logo = get_by_id("logo");
    var logo_height = logo.clientHeight;  
    var menu = get_by_id("menu");
    var menu_height = menu.clientHeight; 
    var cover_height = logo_height + menu_height;
    var distance_top = (h - cover_height) / 2.5;

    var container = get_by_id("container");
    container.style.paddingTop = distance_top + "px"; 
  }

  w.resize = function () {

    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight; 

    //resize_font;
    var fs = parseInt(w / 26);   
    document.body.style.fontSize = fs + "px";

    //resize_cover;
    var logo = get_by_id("logo");
    var logo_height = logo.clientHeight;  
    var menu = get_by_id("menu");
    var menu_height = menu.clientHeight; 
    var cover_height = logo_height + menu_height;
    var distance_top = (h - cover_height) / 2.5;

    var container = get_by_id("container");
    container.style.paddingTop = distance_top + "px"; 
  }
}
```

Now I want to refactor the code for resizing font and cover into a function, but
I can't get it working. I tried this:

```
(function (w) {

  w.init = function () {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight; 

    resize_font;
    resize_cover;
  }

  w.resize = function () {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight; 

    resize_font;
    resize_cover;
  }

  function resize_cover() {
    var logo = get_by_id("logo");
    var logo_height = logo.clientHeight;  
    var menu = get_by_id("menu");
    var menu_height = menu.clientHeight; 
    var cover_height = logo_height + menu_height;
    var distance_top = (h - cover_height) / 2.5;

    var container = get_by_id("container");
    container.style.paddingTop = distance_top + "px";        
  }

  function resize_font() {
    var fs = parseInt(w / 26);   
    document.body.style.fontSize = fs + "px";        
  }
}
```

The console doesn'T show any errors, but resizing isn't happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ehhh, what exactly do you think that `resize_font;` does?

Comment: Uhhh, resizing font_size.

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke your functions in your init and resize event functions.
You have:

```
resize_font;
resize_cover;
```

You need:

```
resize_font();
resize_cover();
```

The name of a function is just a reference to it, which is why you don't see any errors. What you currently have is similar to saying:

```
var x = 1;
x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your problem is this:

```
resize_font;
resize_cover;
```

I think you mean

```
resize_font();
resize_cover();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's seems like you forgot to execute the functions, just mentioned the pointer.

**please try to change:**

```
resize_font;
resize_cover;
```

**to**

```
resize_font();
resize_cover();
```